# Air for iOS webview - Close webview on SSL error

Tags: ios, ssl, air, error-handling

In the StageWebView in Air for iOS, if there is a SSL certificate error, by default it will prompt the user with:

> "A secure connection with this site cannot be verified.  Would you
>   still like to proceed?
>
> The certificate you are viewing does not match the name of the site
>   you are trying to view."

When this occurs, is there any way to stop the message from occurring and just hide the webview?

I've added error handling code:

```
function webview_error(event:ErrorEvent) {  
    trace(event);
    webView.stage = null;
    isConnected = false;
}
```

But it only fires if the user hits "No"  I don't want them to have that option to avoid Man in the Middle attacks.

Thanks.